# Android 4.1.1 Java code is not showing inline highlight (Kotlin works fine)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I updated the android studio to 4.1.1.
but no highlight is showing in java code but its showing in Kotlin code

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`?

Comment: I tried didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the plugin Markdown. I have to update the markdown and kotlin puglin and restarted the android studio, it's solved the issue.
[image]